# What is data-cfsrc in HTML

Tags: html

What is data-cfsrc attribute of HTML ??

I got it inside an img tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any attribute starting `data-` is an arbitrary data string attached to any element. It can be queried bt Javascript for whatever purpose the designer has in mind.

Answer (score 14):

As Mike W says, any attribute starting data- is an arbitrary data string attached to any element. The data-cfsrc is used by CloudFlare's [Mirage](http://blog.cloudflare.com/mirage2-solving-mobile-speed) feature to lazy-load images to improve website performance.

Comment: Note that mirage mode cause huge CLS, it's still in beta and should not be used on production